# Import Luxon into LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, static-resources, third-party

I am trying to use Luxon in a LWC.

I believe I am messing up the syntax of the decomposition of DateTime from the library.

Following the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library

### My Steps

I started by downloading Luxon from GitHub: https://github.com/moment/luxon

I extracted luxon-master.zip and rezipped the /src directory.

I renamed the .zip "luxon". I uploaded this to static resources as "Luxon".

### My Import:

```
import DateTime from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Luxon';
import {loadScript} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
```

### renderedCallback()

```
renderedCallback() {
    loadScript(this, DateTime + '/luxon.js')
.then(() => { /* callback */ });
}
```

### Use Luxon DateTime

```
get luxonDate() {
    return DateTime.now().toISO();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an import, you need to attach Luxon to the window element to get it. Change the very first part from:

```
var luxon = ...
```

To:

```
window.luxon = ...
```

Or, alternatively, you can add a line at the end:

```
window.luxon = luxon
```

Next, you need to reference it in your code, so:

```
return luxon.DateTime.now().toISO();
```

---

You can also convert this script to a "native" ES6 script.

Instead of attaching luxon to window, create a new LWC called luxon, delete the .html file, copy the luxon source to the .js file, and add this as the very last line:

```
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
export { DateTime };
```

Then you can use it in your script directly:

```
import { DateTime } from 'c/luxon';
```

...

```
return DateTime.now().toISO();
```

[Functional Example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/l1wxa1U6ZiMeeqFBeUn5/src/app.js)

You can also choose to export `luxon`, and use it as above (e.g. `luxon.DateTime...`) or each individual part that you need.

---

Edit: I also see that they have an [ES6 module](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/install?id=es6). This would be a copy-paste scenario, you can use it verbatim with no modifications.

---

Edit 2: As noted in a comment, this trick only works if the file can be minified to 128KiB (131,072) characters long.

Comment: I could only import Luxon as a single js file by changing the first declaration on the library file from `var luxon=` to `window.luxon=`. Any ideas on how to import it without modifying its source code? I couldn't understand your first example (how would I assign it to `window.luxon` if I can't even reference it?)

Comment: @RenatoOliveira See [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_guidance). LWC uses "strict mode," which among other things, doesn't allow `var luxon` to become a global, thus unusable outside of the source file. Your two basic choices are: modify luxon source to attach to window.luxon, or use the ES6 module, as demonstrated in the link.

Comment: It is worth noting that the "integrate ES6 module as LWC component" workaround, i.e. copy-pasting the library's source into a component JS and importing it from another component works, but the JS file size is limited to 131 KB. If it exceeds that size, you will get this error message when deploying: ```
Failed to save Lightning Component Resource [lwc/foo/foo.js] of Lightning Component Bundle [foo]. Error: Value too long for field: Source maximum length is:131072
```

Comment: @AlexSuzuki I knew about that limit, but you're right, having it here makes sense. I've edited that in.